# Not a group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've found many similar questions to this and basically I need to put on the group by, all columns that are not aggregated by a function. And yet, this doesn't seem to work.

```
select UC.executionTime as executionTime,
       UC.aggregationTime as aggregationTime,
       UC.totalTime as totalTime,
       case when UC.numberExecutions <= UD.NUMBEREXECUTIONS then UC.numberExecutions
          else UD.NUMBEREXECUTIONS
          end as numberExecutions,
       (avg(UD.AVERAGETIME)*(count(UD.AVERAGETIME))+avg(UC.executionTime))/((count(UD.AVERAGETIME))+1.0) as averageTime,
       UC.layer as layer,
       UC.domain as domain,
       UC.name as name,
       UC.componentType as componentType,
       UC.operation as operation,
       UC.version as version,
       "UseRateDay" as indicator
  from UCtable as UC, USE_RATE_DAY as UD
  where UC.name=UD.NAME and UC.layer=UD.LAYER 
        and UC.domain=UD.DOMAIN and UC.componentType=UD.COMPONENTTYPE 
        and UC.operation=UD.OPERATION AND UC.version=UD.VERSION and UC.indicator="UseRateDay" and (floor(UC.executionTime/(24*60*60*1000))*(24*60*60*1000) <= UD.EXECUTIONTIME and (ceil(UC.executionTime/(24*60*60*1000)) * (24*60*60*1000))*2 > UD.EXECUTIONTIME)   
  group by executionTime, aggregationTime,totalTime, numberExecutions,layer, domain, componentType, name, operation, version
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: `indicator` column in `GROUP BY`?

Comment: doesn't seem to work is very vague!  What specifically isn't working the syntax? The expected aggregation results?  It would be good to include some sample data as well as a sample expected result based on that data.

Comment: With or without indicator, it says not a group by expression and it's missing statements from the select in the group by.

Answer (score 1):

you have two different **numberExecutions** columns ( used in the case stmt) one in each of your tables aliased as UC and UD.

so your group by needs to have these 2 columns explicitly listed  like this :

```
group by UC.numberExecutions , UD.NUMBEREXECUTIONS , other columns
```

you have currently included only one of them numberExecutions in group by clause and since you have not aliased it ... is causing you issues. once you alias it it will complain about any other missing columns in group by that it needs.

Also the indicator column isnt needed in the group by as it is a static value.

And most importantly you should always alias your columns everywhere you are using them to avoid confusions. This is just a good practice.